# Webscarab : unable to view https sites

Tags: https, proxy, webproxy, webscarab

I am running webscarab from the jar

% java -jar WebScarab-ng-0.2.1.one-jar.jar

For normal websites (http) i am able to analyze the packets using webscarab.  But if i enter any secure site (https), say https://www.gmail.com i am unable to view the pages.

I tried generating a certificate file for the site using the instructions from 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Generating_Custom_SSL_Certificates_for_WebScarab

But still i am unable to view any https webpages.

I have configured proxy in firefox to localhost:8008 for all requests.

In the backend i am getting " incomplete ssl connection?".

---

Answer (score -1):

You need to give more information. What browser are you using? What is the exact error message you are getting? Is is ALL SSL sites that you cannot access? Have you set the SSL proxy as well as the non-SSL proxy settings in the browser? Is the site using client SSL certificates?

Comment: I configured proxy settings in firefox to localhost:8008 for all request. 
I am unable to access any ssl sites.  Where should i keep the .pem files created by cert.sh when i execute through the jar?